# How to create a first-person "space flight" camera

Tags: rust, 3d, game-engine, matrix-multiplication, game-development

I'm currently attempting to create a first-person space flight camera.

First, allow me to define what I mean by that.

**Notice** that I am currently using Row-Major matrices in my math library (meaning, the basis vectors in my 4x4 matrices are laid out in rows, and the affine translation part is in the fourth row). Hopefully this helps clarify the order in which I multiply my matrices.

**What I have so Far**

So far, I have successfully implemented a simple first-person camera view. The code for this is as follows:

```
 fn fps_camera(&mut self) -> beagle_math::Mat4 {
    let pitch_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::rotate_x(self.pitch_in_radians);
    let yaw_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::rotate_y(self.yaw_in_radians);

    let view_matrix = yaw_matrix.get_transposed().mul(&pitch_matrix.get_transposed());
    let translate_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::translate(&self.position.mul(-1.0));

    translate_matrix.mul(&view_matrix)
}
```

This works as expected. I am able to walk around and look around with the mouse.

**What I am Attempting to do**

However, an obvious limitation of this implementation is that since pitch and yaw is always defined relative to a global "up" direction, the moment I pitch more than 90 degrees, getting the world to essentially being upside-down, my yaw movement is inverted.

What I would like to attempt to implement is what could be seen more as a first-person "space flight" camera. That is, no matter what your current orientation is, pitching up and down with the mouse will always translate into up and down in the game, relative to your current orientation. And yawing left and right with your mouse will always translate into a left and right direction, relative to your current orientation.

Unfortunately, this problem has got me stuck for days now. Bear with me, as I am new to the field of linear algebra and matrix transformations. So I must be misunderstanding or overlooking something fundamental. What I've implemented so far might thus look... stupid and naive :) Probably because it is.

**What I've Tried so far**

The way that I always end up coming back to thinking about this problem is to basically redefine the world's orientation every frame. That is, in a frame, you translate, pitch, and yaw the world coordinate space using your view matrix. You then somehow redefine this orientation as being the new default or zero-rotation. By doing this, you can then, in your next frame apply new pitch and yaw rotations based on this new default orientation, which (by my thinking, anyways), would mean that mouse movement will always translate directly to up, down, left, and right, no matter how you are oriented, because you are basically always redefining the world coordinate space in terms relative to what your previous orientation was, as opposed to the simple first-person camera, which always starts from the same initial coordinate space.

The latest code I have which attempts to implement my idea is as follows:

```
 fn space_camera(&mut self) -> beagle_math::Mat4 {
    let previous_pitch_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::rotate_x(self.previous_pitch);
    let previous_yaw_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::rotate_y(self.previous_yaw);
    let previous_view_matrix = previous_yaw_matrix.get_transposed().mul(&previous_pitch_matrix.get_transposed());

    let pitch_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::rotate_x(self.pitch_in_radians);
    let yaw_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::rotate_y(self.yaw_in_radians);

    let view_matrix = yaw_matrix.get_transposed().mul(&pitch_matrix.get_transposed());
    let translate_matrix = beagle_math::Mat4::translate(&self.position.mul(-1.0));

    // SAVES
    self.previous_pitch += self.pitch_in_radians;
    self.previous_yaw += self.yaw_in_radians;

    // RESETS
    self.pitch_in_radians = 0.0;
    self.yaw_in_radians = 0.0;

    translate_matrix.mul(&(previous_view_matrix.mul(&view_matrix)))
}
```

This, however, does nothing to solve the issue. It actually gives the exact same result and problem as the fps camera.

My thinking behind this code is basically: Always keep track of an accumulated pitch and yaw (in the code that is the *previous_pitch* and *previous_yaw*) based on deltas each frame. The deltas are *pitch_in_radians* and *pitch_in_yaw*, as they are always reset each frame.

I then start off by constructing a view matrix that would represent how the world was orientated previously, that is the *previous_view_matrix*. I then construct a new view matrix based on the deltas of this frame, that is the *view_matrix*.

I then attempt to do a view matrix that does this:

1. Translate the world in the opposite direction of what represents the camera's current position. Nothing is different here from the FPS camera.
2. Orient that world according to what my orientation has been so far (using the *previous_view_matrix*. What I would want this to represent is the default starting point for the deltas of my current frame's movement.
3. Apply the deltas of the current frame using the current view matrix, represented by *view_matrix*

My hope was that in step 3, the previous orientation would be seen as a starting point for a new rotation. That if the world was upside-down in the previous orientation, the *view_matrix* would apply a yaw in terms of the camera's "up", which would then avoid the problem of inverted controls.

I must surely be either attacking the problem from the wrong angle, or misunderstanding essential parts of matrix multiplication with rotations.

Can anyone help pin-point where I'm going wrong?

**[EDIT] - Rolling even when you only pitch and yaw the camera**

For anyone just stumbling upon this, I fixed it by a combination of the marked answer and Locke's answer (ultimately, in the example given in my question, I also messed up the matrix multiplication order).

Additionally, when you get your camera right, you may stumble upon the odd side-effect that holding the camera stationary, and just pitching and yawing it about (such as moving your mouse around in a circle), will result in your world slowly rolling as well.

This is not a mistake, this is how rotations work in 3D. Kevin added a comment in his answer that explains it, and additionally, I also found [this GameDev Stack Exchange answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/123535/unwanted-roll-when-rotating-camera-with-pitch-and-yaw) explaining it in further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that two numbers, pitch and yaw, provide *insufficient degrees of freedom* to represent consistent free rotation behavior in space without any “horizon”. Two numbers can represent a *look-direction vector* but they cannot represent the third component of camera orientation, called *roll* (rotation about the “depth” axis of the screen). As a consequence, no matter how you implement the controls, you will find that in some orientations the camera rolls strangely, because the *effect of trying to do the math with this information* is that every frame the roll is picked/reconstructed based on the pitch and yaw.

The minimal solution to this is to add a roll component to your camera state. However, this approach (“Euler angles”) is both tricky to compute with and has numerical stability issues (“gimbal lock”).

Instead, you should represent your camera/player orientation as a **quaternion**, a mathematical structure that is good for representing arbitrary rotations. Quaternions are used somewhat like rotation matrices, but have fewer components; you'll multiply quaternions by quaternions to apply player input, and convert quaternions to matrices to render with.

It is very common for general purpose game engines to use quaternions for describing objects' rotations. I haven't personally written quaternion camera code (yet!) but I'm sure the internet contains many examples and longer explanations you can work from.

Comment: Hey Kevin! :)

Luckily, I have actually already implemented Quaternions in my math library, and have used them to make rotation matrices for my view matrix. I removed them again because I tried to simplify my problem down to as few moving parts and concepts as possible. Thinking that I might hit gimbal lock, but might be able to still implement a rough draft using only euler angles. However, I see that approach might have been too naive.

I'll try and see what I can do and come back :) Won't forget to mark as answer based on what I find, I promise!

Comment: @CodingBeagle It's quite possible to use Euler angles and not have any such problems in practice, but the math will end up being “convert from Euler angles to some more general representation, apply player input, then convert back” and so it's almost entirely an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Also, in relation to what you said: "As a consequence, no matter how you implement the controls, you will find that in some orientations the camera rolls strangely". I might have hit this side effect at some point. I remember making a different looking attempt of applying deltas to a rotation matrix that is continuously being stored for the next frame, and hit upon this odd artifact, where I basically got what I wanted (in terms of yaw never inverting, no matter the orientation), but where, if the camera stood still and I just pitched and yawed around, it was as if the world would roll.

Comment: Either that, or I hit upon some sort of floating-point accumulation between frames that gave some unfortunate side-effect.

Comment: @CodingBeagle "if the camera stood still and I just pitched and yawed around, it was as if the world would roll" — That's actually a normal consequence of fully relative camera rotation, because rotations don't commute — `A * B * A.inverse() * B.inverse()` isn't the identity rotation. Picture it this way: If you're standing on a sphere, and you walk forward a significant portion of its circumference and turn 90° to the right, then repeat that a total of four times, you won't come back to where you started. Rotations work the same.

Comment: You can also see the same effect in some simple 3D model viewing programs — grab for rotation and move the mouse in circles, and the model will gradually roll.

Comment: Hey @KevinReid. Just wanted to say that I just tried to re-implement my try with Quaternions, and also added the roll axis. 

Coupled with the tips from Locke, I actually managed to get a fully relative camera going that seems to work beautifully :) Your point about rotation not being commutative was also extremely helpful, as it definitely will have saved me a ton of hair-pulling but not realizing this is a normal side effect. It also made me search more around for this phenomena, which lead me to this extremely helpful post on the same issue:

Comment: [Rotation Unwanted Roll](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/123535/unwanted-roll-when-rotating-camera-with-pitch-and-yaw)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lot of the difficulty you are having is due to trying to normalize the transformation to apply the new translation. It seems like this is probably a large part of what is tripping you up. I would suggest changing how you store your position and rotation. Instead, try letting your view matrix define your position.

```rust
/// Apply rotation based on the change in mouse position
pub fn on_mouse_move(&mut self, dx: f32, dy: f32) {
    // I think this is correct, but it might need tweaking
    let rotation_matrix = Mat4::rotate_xy(-y, x);

    self.apply_movement(&rotation_matrix, &Vec3::zero())
}

/// Append axis-aligned movement relative to the camera and rotation
pub fn apply_movement(&mut self, rotation: &Mat4<f32>, translation: &Vec3<f32>) {
    // Create transformation matrix for translation
    let translation = Mat4::translate(translation);

    // Append translation and rotation to existing view matrix
    self.view_matrix = self.view_matrix * translation * rotation;
}

/// You can get the position from the last column [x, y, z, w] of your view matrix.
pub fn translation(&self) -> Vec3<f32> {
    self.view_matrix.column(3).into()
}
```

I made a couple assumptions about the library:

- `Mat4` implements `Mul<Self>` so you do not need to call `x.mul(y)` explicitly and can instead use `x * y`. Same goes for `Sub`.
- There exists a `Mat4::rotate_xy` function. If there isn't one, it would be equivalent to `Mat4::rotate_xyz(delta_pitch, delta_yaw, 0.0)` or `Mat4::rotate_x(delta_pitch) * Mat4::rotate_y(delta_yaw)`.

I'm somewhat eyeballing the equations so hopefully this is correct. The main idea is to take the delta from the previous inputs and create matrices from that which can then be added on top of the previous `view_matrix`. If you attempt to take the difference after creating transformation matrices it will only be more work for you (and your processor).

As a side note I see you are using `self.position.mul(-1.0)`. This tells me that your projection matrix is probably backwards. You likely want to adjust your projection matrix by scaling it by a factor of -1 in the z axis.

Comment: Hey @Locke! Thank you a bunch for the additional help. I used the knowledge from Kevin's post with your implementation tips, and seemingly got it working!